# How to change sql_mode at runtime

Tags: php, mysql

My MySQL server's `sql_mode` setting is set to `STRICT`. I want to change it to `TRADITIONAL` for a particular application I'm developing. However it's not possible for me to do this at the server level.

Is it possible to change the `sql_mode` setting at runtime from my PHP scripts?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Hmm this should work

```
// connect to mysql and call the first query
mysqli_query($conn, "SET SESSION sql_mode = 'TRADITIONAL'");
```

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are near their end of life. Switch to `mysqli_*` functions instead: `mysqli_query($conn, "SET SESSION sql_mode = 'TRADITIONAL'");`.

Comment: hi @MajidFouladpour i tried you code  in PHP 5.6 and i use mysql 5.7 `mysqli_query($conn, "SET SESSION sql_mode = 'TRADITIONAL'");` but  can't work . so please help

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION FOR WORDPRESS:**

For someone who wants to achieve the result in WordPress, following is my solution:

Place the following function in functions.php file of your theme / main page of your plugin:

```
function get_zeroed_datetime() {
    $modes = array("SET SESSION sql_mode = 'TRADITIONAL'");
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->set_sql_mode($modes);
    return '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
}
```

When performing a DB insert (for example), use it like so:

```
$wpdb->insert('test_table',
            array(
                'verified_on' => get_zeroed_datetime()          
            ),
            array(              
                '%s'
            ));
```

where `'verified_on'` is a column name of the DATETIME format.

**WHAT THE CODE ACHIEVES:**

If `sql_mode` is set to `STRICT` on the server, then it won't allow you to insert zeroed values in DATETIME column. The above code helps in solving this issue.