# MySQL insert query with missing not null fields

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, insert

I currently trying to use an Object Relational Mapper for CodeIgniter and I'm experiencing something I did not expect.

I have a table with a couple of fields, some of which are NOT NULL. An insert query is which is missing of the NOT NULL fields is generated -- a new row is added but with blanks for those fields.

I did not know MySQL would disregard the NOT NULL fields that aren't present in the query and insert the row anyways. Is there a way to restrict this?

-**Edit**-

Let me add a few more details and try to explain it a bit more

Here is a sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `color` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT '',
 `shape` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `size` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

Here is a sample query:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`shape`) VALUES ('foo')
```

I don't have `size` in my query yet it still adds the row - is this expected?

(The sample query was run in phpMyAdmin)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE (table_name)`

Comment: Is a NULL being written or an empty string? An empty string will pass the NOT NULL constraint.

Comment: `NOT NULL` ensures the value stored will never be `NULL`, but the string "NULL" is not the same thing. `NULL` is just a placeholder to indicate the lack of any value...

Comment: @AJ @Thomas @OMGPonnies I've edited my question. Please let me know if you'd like me to clarify anything. Thanks

Comment: @RS7: The table & insert you posted results in `Error 1364: Field "size" doesn't have a default value` when I test on MySQL 5.1.49.  The error is what I'd expect on pretty much any database...

Comment: @OMGPonnies: I'm currently running XAMPP with MySQL 5.1.41. I've just read about strict mode and tried it out. Apparently it works and gives me the Error 1364 but it seems less a lot less forgiving concerning other things. It'd probably give me headaches with the framework code. What do you think? Is your MySQL set to strict? Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empty string is not the same thing as `NULL`. Perhaps ORM inserts just `''` for those fields.

Comment: If I don't pass anything for that field in an insert query, does that result in an empty string or a NULL for that field?

Answer (score 6):

I believe the accepted answer is incorrect, given the question's test INSERT statement. It looks to me like MySQL's "strict mode" is turned off for this table or database. From [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables):

> Strict mode controls how MySQL handles input values that are invalid or **missing**... A value is missing when a new row to be inserted does not contain a value for a non-NULL column that has no explicit DEFAULT clause in its definition...
>
> If you are not using strict mode (that is, neither STRICT_TRANS_TABLES nor STRICT_ALL_TABLES is enabled), **MySQL inserts adjusted values for invalid or missing values** and produces warnings.

You can find out how your database is running with these queries:

```
SELECT @@global.sql_mode;
SELECT @@session.sql_mode;
```

Changing these values is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5273824/27846

Answer (score 1):

Not a codeigniter dev, but I would hazard a guess that the issue is your ORM is passing blank values on to the database, I would check your logs to verify this and if its the case, check your ORM if it has some validation options.